# How to customize view that contains Navigation bar, segmented control and table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

How to customize view that contains Navigation bar, segmented control and table view ? Tab each segment of segmented control, show different table views. Help me. I'm using storyboard
Like this[image]

Comment: What customization you want to do?

Comment: This is my task, and don't know how to do @@

Comment: So your task is just to update the tableview when segment control button is tapped or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to link your segmented control to the View controller as an outlet in your header file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

Next you will want to also link an IBAction method to this segmented control for when the user selects a segment in your header file.

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender;
```

Once you have done this, and assuming you have three separate arrays of data to reload the tableview with when the user selects a segments you can do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex){

case 0:

//create cell and assign array1 data
     break;
case 1:

//create cell and assign array2 data
     break;
case 2:

//create cell and assign array3 data
     break;
default:
     break;

}

return cell;

}
```

Then in your IBAction method just call

```
[self.yourTableView reloadData];
```

This will allow you to reload your tableView with the correct data based on the selected segment.

hope this helps